# Alternate definitions of $\eta_{R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

In the text "Functions of One Complex Variable" by Robert E. Greene and Steven G. Krantz, the authors give a tedious definition of $\eta_{R}$. What  are alternate definitions ?

**Background**

> $\text{Definition (1.1)}$
>
> The author defines $\eta_{R}$ our Keyhole Contour  such that
>   $$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \eta_{R}^{1}(t)  =  t + i/\sqrt{2R},  \, \, \, \,   1/\sqrt{2R} \leq t \leq R,$$
>
> $$\eta_{R}^{2}(t)= Re^{it}, \, \, \, \,  \theta_{0} \leq t \leq 2 \pi - \theta_{0},$$
>
> where $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0}(R) = \sin^{-1}(1/(R \sqrt{2R}))$
>
> $$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \eta_{R}^{3}(t)  =  R -t -i/\sqrt{2R},  \, \, \, \, 0 \leq t \leq R-1/\sqrt{2R},$$
>
> $$\eta_{R}^{4}(t)  =  e^{it}/\sqrt{R}, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \pi/4 \leq t \leq 7 \pi /4.$$

$\text{Remark}$

For those who don't have the text a picture has been provided for convenience

$\text{Figure (1.1)}$

$\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,  \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, $ [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is worth a thousand words.  $\eta_R$ is a parametrization of the contour that goes at height $1/\sqrt{2R}$ above the positive real axis from the inner circle to the outer circle, then counterclockwise around the outer circle to $1/\sqrt{2R}$ below the positive real axis, then horizontally left to the inner circle, and finally clockwise around the inner circle to the starting point.

Comment: Well, in any case 60 words...